# Drawer items Selected effect in android

Tags: android, android-adapter

**Overview**::

- I have a navigation drawer
- I am setting the `textView` color in the adapter when position is `0`
  to `red`
- On selecting different element in the list that `textView` is set to
  `red` and others to `black`
- So at anytime only one `textview` must be set in `red`(selected
  adapter) others in `black`
- Also to note that the reason i am setting  red for `textview` in
  adapter when position is o because since its the first fragment shown when it is loaded for the first time
- This must be un-selected when i am selecting other adapter which is not
  happening

**Code i use is**::

```
private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // display view for selected nav drawer item
        displayView(position);
        setNavDrawerItemNormal();
        title=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        title.setTextColor(getApplicationContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.red));

    }
}


public void setNavDrawerItemNormal()
{
    for (int i=0; i< mDrawerList.getChildCount(); i++)
    {
        View v = mDrawerList.getChildAt(i);
        TextView txtview = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title));
        txtview.setTextColor(getApplicationContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private GridView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    private TextView title;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);


        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Find People
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Photos
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Communities, Will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1), true, "22"));
        // Pages
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1), true, "50+"));


        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        //getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
                ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
    ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
            setNavDrawerItemNormal();
            title=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            title.setTextColor(getApplicationContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.red));

        }
    }


    public void setNavDrawerItemNormal()
    {
        for (int i=0; i< mDrawerList.getChildCount(); i++)
        {
            View v = mDrawerList.getChildAt(i);
            TextView txtview = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title));
            txtview.setTextColor(getApplicationContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* *
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new FragmentOne();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new FragmentTwo();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new FragmentThree();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new FragmentFour();
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new FragmentFive();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }




    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

}
```

**NavDrawerListAdapter.java**

```
public class NavDrawerListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;

    public NavDrawerListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems){
        this.context = context;
        this.navDrawerItems = navDrawerItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return navDrawerItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {       
        return navDrawerItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null);
        }

        ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);

        if (position == 0) 
        { 
            txtTitle.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
        }

        imgIcon.setImageResource(navDrawerItems.get(position).getIcon());        
        txtTitle.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getTitle());


        return convertView;
    }

}
```

`NOTE`:: I Can achieve my objective with application variable, but i am trying to do without it, programatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main idea that You don't need to have any additional variables in adapter / activity, because Android component already have one for lists with single choice. The following solution works fine in your case:

- Assume your layout (**activity_main.xml**):

  ```
  <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">
      <!-- The main content view -->
      <FrameLayout
          android:id="@+id/content_frame"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />
      <!-- The navigation drawer -->
      <GridView android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
                android:layout_width="240dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
                android:dividerHeight="0dp"
                android:background="#111"/>
  </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
  ```

  Please note `android:choiceMode="singleChoice"` - that property will let the list track selected item by itself.
- Remove all color setting code from the activity. Instead, use setChecked() to let the list know which item is selected:

  ```
  public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

      private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
      private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
      private GridView mDrawerList;
      private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

      // nav drawer title
      private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

      // used to store app title
      private CharSequence mTitle;

      // slide menu items
      private String[] navMenuTitles;
      private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

      private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
      private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

      private TextView title;

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

          mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

          // load slide menu items
          navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

          // nav drawer icons from resources
          navMenuIcons = getResources()
                  .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

          mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
          mDrawerList = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

          navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

          // Recycle the typed array
          navMenuIcons.recycle();

          mDrawerList.setItemChecked(0, true); // NOTE: Set 0 item as checked!
          mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

          // setting the nav drawer list adapter
          adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), navDrawerItems);
          mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

          // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
          getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
          //getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

          mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                  android.R.drawable.ic_input_delete, //nav menu toggle icon
                  R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                  R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
          ) {
              public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                  getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                  // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                  invalidateOptionsMenu();
              }

              public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                  getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                  // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                  invalidateOptionsMenu();
              }
          };
          mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

          if (savedInstanceState == null) {
              // on first time display view for first nav item
              displayView(0);
          }
      }

      /**
       * Slide menu item click listener
       * */
      private class SlideMenuClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
          @Override
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                  long id) {
              displayView(position);
              // NOTE: new item is checked now
              mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
          }
      }

      ...
  }
  ```
- In the adapter - just check if item is checked or not and set corresponding test color:

  ```
  public class NavDrawerListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

      private Context context;
      private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;

      public NavDrawerListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems){
          this.context = context;
          this.navDrawerItems = navDrawerItems;
      }

      @Override
      public int getCount() {
          return navDrawerItems.size();
      }

      @Override
      public Object getItem(int position) {
          return navDrawerItems.get(position);
      }

      @Override
      public long getItemId(int position) {
          return position;
      }

      @Override
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

          if (convertView == null) {
              LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                      context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
              convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null);
          }

          // TODO: Here ViewHolder pattern can be used or
          ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
          TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);

          // NOTE: check which item is Checked an set corresponding text color
          if (((GridView)parent).isItemChecked(position)) {
              txtTitle.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
          } else {
              txtTitle.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
          }

          imgIcon.setImageResource(navDrawerItems.get(position).getIcon());
          txtTitle.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getTitle());


          return convertView;
      }
  }
  ```

With above code, text color will be changed only after pointer up (when you press item it's color will still hold old value). If you need it to change color during pressed state, then use the following code in the adapter:

```
    // NOTE: check which item is Checked an set corresponding text color
    if (((GridView)parent).isItemChecked(position)) {
        //txtTitle.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
        txtTitle.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.red_selector));
    } else {
        //txtTitle.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
        txtTitle.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.black_selector));
    }
```

And provide **color/red_selector.xml** and **color/black_selector.xml**. E.g. **color/black_selector.xml** should look the following way:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/red"/>
    <item android:color="@color/black"/>
</selector>
```